# iPOJO @Requires is null

Tags: osgi, ipojo

When I use the iPOJO and the @Requires annotation it is not injected into the consumer.

**Consumer:**

```
@Component
@Provides
@Instantiate
@Content(name = "bean")
public class BeanContentHandler extends ContentHandler
{  
    @Requires
    private IContentMapper mapper;
```

**Provider:**

```
@Component
@Provides
public class JcromContentMapper implements IContentMapper
{
    protected static final Jcrom JCROM = new Jcrom(true, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two potential issues:

- What is doing the @Content annotation ?
- Your provider is not instantiated (add an @Instantiate annotation on it)

Can you also tell me where is used the mapper field ?

Comment: The @Instantiate was the issue.  The annotation has nothing to do with it.